# filter out exception messages from unittest output

Tags: python, python-unittest, output-formatting

Is it possible to scrap all the exception text that comes as output from using `unittest`?

I.e., if I have a bunch of tests, and some of them throw exceptions, the `unittest` module takes it upon itself to print in red (in IDLE at least) all the exceptions. Is there a way to just not print the exceptions (but leave in any text I print using the `print` keyword?

For example, I have text to print in a `tearDownClass()` function, and while I'd like that to print, it'd be nice if it wasn't followed by 30 lines of red exception text. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do the unhandled exceptions occur in the first place?

Comment: If print is a keyword, you should upgrade to Python 3. Anyhow, you can always redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr and afterwards analyse their content. BTW: I guess that IDLE colours all stderr output red, maybe you could use that to your advantage. Lastly, you can tell the unittest library to swallow all output and instead structure your tests on the outcome, not on intermediate exceptions that may or may not be caught and handled.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I don't think the exceptions are considered unhandled, they are, I think, caught by `unittest` method calls such as `self.assertEqual()`. It's possible I'm wrong on this, but when I tried the solution below, the exceptions still came up, which makes me think that they have already been caught, and are merely being printed by the `unittest` module. The reason why I have to allow exceptions like this is that I am attempting to automate homework grading - students' code may throw exceptions, and while I don't care what they are, I need to know that they're there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The class I'm grading for has a strict policy of using Python 2.7, because there are certain features (I'm told) that work differently or are easier to explain to students. And thank you, I will look into redirecting stderr.

Comment: @user3475234: Yes, that's the problem: why are they caught by the framework and not your code? If they're the expected behaviour, you'd probably use framework methods that assert they happen. If not, they indicate a problem and the framework is completely right to be telling you about them.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Well, it's not expected - it's a one or the other situation. A student's code can work fine, and throw no exceptions. Or, their homework could even return an incorrect value, and throw an exception such as "Test failed", provided by the `unittest` module. I understand that `unittest` correctly prints the exceptions it should print - I just want to get rid of the output, because the grading is based on a "pass/fail" basis per test - if it throws an exception, they don't get points. If it doesn't, they do - it doesn't matter what the exception is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you just want a self-defined logger, right?

Put all the unit tests in a bit `try-except` block and catch all the exceptions. Then print it out as you like.

```
...
try:
    def test1(unit.tests):
        pass
    def test2(unit.tests):
        pass
except Exception, e:
    print 'here is the exception message', repr(e)
    # Use your own function to deal with print function or whatever you want here

...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, according to [comment-41597224](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480216/python-unittest-output-selection/41597224#comment41597224_26480216), you want to deliberately wipe useful output because you feel it's not your problem.

In that case, replace/make relevant changes to `Lib\unittest\result.py:_exc_info_to_string` or a method that uses it that applies to your specific case (probably, `addError` or `addFailure`).

Alternatively, you can pipe the output to an independent script/command that would postprocess it with regexes.

- If results happen to be written to `stdout` while exceptions to `stderr`, it's as simple as `2>nul` at the command line.

But, I still advise against this. You do care what exceptions you get, because:

- they might turn out to be a result of YOUR mistake as well as student's
- you could reply with the verbatim output rather than just "pass/fail" that is both less work for you and gives the loser a better hint to fix it

You can get the best of both worlds if you make it so that you get BOTH the (filtered) summary and the opportunity to see the full output if you suspect something is not right.